# estimated marginal means of a MANCOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics, manova, emmeans

I have constructed a model that accounted for a covariate. There are two dependent variables ("A","B") and two independent variables ("C", "D") and one continuous covariate ("E"). I ran a MANCOVA as follows:

```
x<-cbind(A,B) #combining dependent variables
y<-cbind(C,D) #combining independent variables
fit<-manova(x~y+E)
summary(fit, test="Pillai")
```

This all worked perfectly and I found that there was an effect of the covariate on the dependent variables. Therefore I want to account for the covariance with an estimated marginal mean, using the emmeans package. However, when I try to run the following code I receive this error:

```
library(emmeans)
emmeans(fit,~y+E)

>Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'spc.l$Ghopper.Start..g.' not 
found
>Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is 
needed
```

Here is my data:

```
 structure(list(ï..insect = c(105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 110L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
125L, 126L, 127L, 128L), C = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("Pair A 7p:35c-35p:7c", "Pair B 7p:35c-28p:14c"
), class = "factor"), D = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor"), E = c(0.357, 0.259, 0.128, 0.104, 0.248, 
0.111, 0.218, 0.213, 0.13, 0.123, 0.335, 0.22, 0.247, 0.295, 
0.297, 0.219, 0.132, 0.194, 0.207, 0.266, 0.234), A = c(0.025333333, 
0.041666665, 0.043833332, 0.046333331, 0.108499995, 0.051999997, 
0.101833329, 0.06083333, 0.059499998, 0.056166664, 0.017833333, 
0.053666664, 0.066333331, 0.025499998, 0.073666664, 0.149333324, 
0.044666665, 0.047499998, 0.051833331, 0.020499999, 0.062499997
), B = c(0.050666667, 0.020333321, 0.023166668, 0.029666645, 
0.032499992, 0.028999981, 0.029166671, 0.024166656, 0.025500002, 
0.020833325, 0.021166667, 0.038333304, 0.023666669, 0.022499981, 
0.040333336, 0.121666569, 0.023333335, 0.017500002, 0.01816666, 
0.018500001, 0.024499989)), .Names = c("ï..insect", "C", "D", 
"E", "A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

I am sure that there is a simple fix to this problem, but I am a bit lost and there are few questions posted on stackexchange about emmeans!

Comment: Can you provide your data by pasting the result of `dput(df)` where `df` is your data?

Comment: I have attached my data to the question! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the effect of the covariate on the dependent variables, unfortunately.

Comment: I apologize, I have but in the correct data. Thanks!

Comment: I will check this tomorrow, but in the meantime could you try using C+D in place of y (in both the model and emmeans specs)? It might work that way.

Comment: I confirm, `fit<-manova(cbind(A,B)~cbind(C,D)+E, data = df); emmeans(fit, ~cbind(C,D)+E)` works @rvl. You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works, computationally:

```
R> fit = manova(x ~ cbind(C, D) + E, data = dat)
R> ref_grid(fit)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    C = 1.5238
    D = 1.2857
    E = 0.21605
    rep.meas = multivariate response levels: A, B
R> emmeans(fit, ~ C + D + E)
       C        D         E     emmean          SE df   lower.CL   upper.CL
 1.52381 1.285714 0.2160476 0.04438095 0.005377854 17 0.03303467 0.05572723

Results are averaged over the levels of: rep.meas 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

I'll say more later about these results. So, replacing `y` with `cbind(C, D)` in the model call will make it work (computationally). Using `y` directly, I get an error message:

```
R> fit0 = manova(x ~ y+E, data = dat)
R> ref_grid(fit0)
Error in model.matrix(trms, m, contrasts.arg = object$contrasts)[, nm,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

This is not the same error message shown in the OP, and I can only guess that the scoping is different somehow. But what is happening here is that `C` and `D` are actually factors, not numeric predictors. `cbind(C,D)` converts these to a numeric matrix with two columns. There is some technical reason for the error that I need to investigate and correct.

But the *important* thing is that neither `fit` nor `fit0` is model you want to use for post-hoc comparisons, because after all, `C` and `D` are factors. The reference grid, and hence the EMMs, for `fit` are based on the *average* values of the numeric recodings of `C` and `D`, and the average `E`. That's why there is only one row of `emmeans` output.

What I think is needed is to take the `cbind` out of the call:

```
R> fit1 = manova(x ~ C + D + E, data = dat)
R> summary(fit1)
          Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)
C          1 0.07083   0.6098      2     16 0.55559
D          1 0.03150   0.2602      2     16 0.77408
E          1 0.37794   4.8606      2     16 0.02242
Residuals 17                                       
R> ref_grid(fit1)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    C = Pair A 7p:35c-35p:7c, Pair B 7p:35c-28p:14c
    D = F, M
    E = 0.21605
    rep.meas = multivariate response levels: A, B
```

Since `E` is numeric and reduced to only its mean, you need not include it in the `emmeans` call:

```
R> emmeans(fit1, ~ C + D)
 C                     D     emmean          SE df    lower.CL   upper.CL
 Pair A 7p:35c-35p:7c  F 0.05021337 0.011726789 17  0.02547201 0.07495473
 Pair B 7p:35c-28p:14c F 0.05576090 0.008808415 17  0.03717677 0.07434503
 Pair A 7p:35c-35p:7c  M 0.01962942 0.016299910 17 -0.01476039 0.05401922
 Pair B 7p:35c-28p:14c M 0.02517695 0.019816637 17 -0.01663250 0.06698640

Results are averaged over the levels of: rep.meas 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

These results are averaged over the two repeated measures in the dependent variable. You might want to separate them out, or average over the levels of some other factor. Since neither `C` nor `D` is significant, I'll just get the EMMs and comparison thereof for `rep.meas`:

```
R> emmeans(fit1, pairwise ~ rep.meas)
$emmeans
 rep.meas     emmean          SE df   lower.CL   upper.CL
 A        0.04551606 0.008547982 17 0.02748139 0.06355073
 B        0.02987426 0.006885079 17 0.01534801 0.04440050

Results are averaged over the levels of: C, D 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast   estimate          SE df t.ratio p.value
 A - B    0.01564181 0.005645167 17   2.771  0.0131

Results are averaged over the levels of: C, D
```

Since `E` is significant and it is a covariate, it might be interesting to see if there is a different slope for each level of `rep.meas`:

```
R> emtrends(fit1, pairwise ~ rep.meas, var = "E")
$emtrends
 rep.meas    E.trend        SE df   lower.CL   upper.CL
 A        -0.3472133 0.1737591 17 -0.7138129 0.01938632
 B         0.0213882 0.1399564 17 -0.2738940 0.31667042

Results are averaged over the levels of: C, D 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast   estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
 A - B    -0.3686015 0.1147521 17  -3.212  0.0051

Results are averaged over the levels of: C, D
```

Also, try this to get a nice graph of the predictions (result not shown):

```
emmip(fit1, rep.meas ~ E|C*D, at=list(E = c(.1,.35)))
```